# Getting a list of cookies set using WatiN

Tags: cookies, watin

Is there a way to get a list of all the cookies set by a website using WatiN?

The IE Browser class in WatiN provides a `GetCookie` method that allows you to retrieve a specific cookie, but I would like to iterate over all the cookies that have been set.

There are two methods that should allow you to get the cookies:

`CookieCollection cookies = _browser.GetCookiesForUrl(new Uri(url));`

and

`CookieContainer cookies = _browser.GetCookieContainerForUrl(new Uri(url));`

But both of these are empty. Also calling the `GetCookie` method for a specific cookie returns null.

Any suggestions of how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I suppose those methods should work as expected, but maybe you are trying to get `HttpOnly` cookies? Many sites/web frameworks sets this flag for important cookies, especially when it comes to "session id" cookies. You can't read them in WatiN and it's really hard to read them at all. I was looking for solution once and only one I got was article: [Retrieve HttpOnly Session Cookie in WebBrowser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/RetrieveHttponlyCookies.aspx)

If you want to know if the site you are trying to get cookies is setting `HttpOnly` flag on the cookie, use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and look in response headers.

Answer (score 5):

Recently I had to deal with this situation. At first I thought the cookies I was looking for were HttpOnly, but I took a look using WireShark and there was no HttpOnly flag.

Not sure why GetCookieContainerForUrl fails in this case, but a client side script call revealed the cookies were still there:

```
ie.Eval("document.cookie");
```

You might want to try that statement before resorting to packet sniffing every time.